# Working with Quick View Forms

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Has anyone had any success working with the Quick View forms and JavaScript in CRM 2013?

I'm attempting to get a value from the related entity.  That value is on the quick view form.  Inspection of the DOM means I can get to it via unsupported means...

```
document.getElementById("cardPatient_cardPatient_contact_birthdate").innerText
```

but I'd rather not.

All the information is there.  I wonder if there's a way to get to it via supported methods.  I'm currently hitting the OData service for the birthdate but it just strikes me as a waste when it's there already.

Answer (score 1):

If you use OData call you already use supported way.

Comment: Agreed.  But I consider it an unnecessary call because I have the data on the form already.  I just can't access it from the form in a supported manner.  Not in any way I know of anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Quick forms attributes are accessible by calling getAttribute() from the control, as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx. Here's the example given on the page:

```
var quickViewMobilePhoneControl = Xrm.Page.getControl("contactQuickForm_contactQuickForm_contact_mobilephone");
 if (quickViewMobilePhoneControl.getAttribute().getValue() == null)
 {
  quickViewMobilePhoneControl.setVisible(false);
 }
```